# FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly SecuGen.FDxSDKPro.Windows.dll or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, .net

Estimados reciban un cordial saludo, solicito por favor su ayuda ante un problema con el ensamblado .NET (SecuGen.FDxSDKPro.Windows.dll) el cual es para desarrolladores .NET. (la version 4 o superior)

Les explico brevemente, no me da ningún inconveniente al usar la dll en mi desarrollo (en C#) desde visual studio 2017, la agrego como referencia, utilizo las clases y corro la aplicación desde el visual y todo marcha bien, incluso genero un ejecutable y *funciona correctamente en mi mismo ordenador*.

El problema es cuando instalo mi aplicación en otros ordenadores (*en los cuales no esta instalado visual studio, solo el .Net Framework 4.7*), allí todo marcha bien hasta el momento en el que inicio el dispositivo al dar click en un botón (Uso de la clase *SGFingerPrintManager*, ect, que pertenecen a la dll), el error que genera es el siguiente:

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly SecuGen.FDxSDKPro.Windows.dll or one of its dependencies

La excepción mismo indica que no encuentra un archivo en disco, pero realmente al generar el ejecutable desde mi pc de desarrollo en el visual studio, el archivo si se agrega, todo se genera correctamente, y sin embargo sigue dando ese problema.

Vale aclarar que tengo todos los permisos, mi app corre en 32 bits, verifique que todo este bien generado. Los controladores estan bien instalados, ya que si se reconoce el dispositivo SecuGen (incluso hago test, con demos de otras versiones anteriores de secugen, solo para probar si el dispositivo es reconocido en el ordenador).

Pido de favor su amable ayuda en este problema que me tiene bastante preocupado y no logro resolverlo.

Posdata: La versión que uso de Secugen es:  `FDx SDK Pro for Windows 3.81`

Comment: Estás usando ClickOnce para  crear un instalador? o simplemente copias la aplicación en los equipos de destino?

Comment: No utilizo ClickOnce para crear el instalador, en lugar de eso hago lo siguiente: Desde el Visual Studio, voy a las propiedades del proyecto, en la sección Publicación, especifico la ruta y verifico los archivos de compilación (botón archivos de compilación). Al final doy click en publicar ahora y genero el ejecutable.

Comment: Eso es ClickOnce :) Asegurate en ese caso de que la dll necesaria está como `Incluir` y no como `Incluir(automatico)`

Comment: Si le cambio de _Incluir(automatico)_ a _Incluir_,e igualmente persiste el problema.

Comment: Hmm..mira también en las propiedades de la dll, si tiene "copia local" a true

Comment: Afirmativo, "copia local" si está en true, verifico eso cada vez que publico.

Comment: Pues ya lo último que se me ocurre: Es posible que esa dll dependa de algun otra que no se esta incluyendo en el instalador. Si sabes de que dll puede depender, asegurate que aparezcan en la pestaña de "Archivos de aplicación" como "incluir". Siento no ser de mas ayuda :)

Comment: En ralidad el manual menciona dos dll que deben estar en el sistema: sgfplib.dll y sgfpamx.dll, esos archivos vienen en una carpeta bin (cuando se descarga el sdk), pero en dicha versiòn no viene cono instalador, sino como que fuera portable.   Ahora esas dll las intento agregar como referencia y me sale un error: Asegurese de que tiene acceso al archivo y de que es un ensamblado o componente COM válido.

Comment: En el equipo donde instalo la aplicacion (que es de 32 bits), las pongo en system 32 y nada. Aparte de eso he intentado registrar con el comando resgsvr y el comando regasm y nada (Creo que toca hacerlo manualmente porque esa version del secugen no viene con instalador).

Comment: No deben estar en system32,sino en la carpeta donde se instala la aplicacion. Haz una busqueda en el disco con el nombre de la app para encontrarla,ya que estara en una carpeta con nombre raro (letras y numeros)

Comment: Pues tambien ya lo hice, en la ruta donde esta instalada las agregue como librerias al momento de generar el ejecutable y sigue el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Instala **Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server 2016**, dado a que el SecuGen trabaja en conjunto con este complemento y el mismo se encuentra en el paquete de Visual Studio, motivo por el que no te da error en tu maquina de desarrollo. Te lo sugiero estaba realizando un proyecto usando el Secugen y daba el mismo error y con eso lo corregí.

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu respuesta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para dar mejores respuestas en el futuro. Saludos.